# Is there a way to check if others are logged into server when you are?

Tags: ssh, users

I am logged into Ubuntu server via `ssh` and I would like to know if another user is logged in via SSH as well. Is there a command that I can run to accomplish this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just type `who`:

```
~$ who
(unknown) tty7         2013-12-06 13:37 (:0)
john      pts/0        2013-12-08 00:16 (192.168.0.100)
jane      pts/1        2013-12-08 00:17 (192.168.0.101)
```

---

#### EDIT

Regarding your bonus question :)

To see login history for users you can use `last -i`. This will show all logins and IP addresses since start of current logfile `/var/log/wtmp`.

Depending on your logrotate you can show previous logs with `last -f /var/log/wtmp.1`, too.

To only show the very last login for each user use `last -i | sort -r | uniq -w 16`

```
~$ last -i | sort -r | uniq -w 20
wtmp begins Sun Dec  1 16:54:49 2013
john    pts/0        192.168.0.100    Sun Dec  8 18:49   still logged in   
jane    pts/1        192.168.0.101    Sun Dec  8 00:17 - 00:34  (00:16)
```

Comment: When I type it it doesn't give me the ip address. Is there  a way to force the ip address?

Comment: You can use `who --ips`. I manually changed the output above to hide my internal network structure :)

Comment: Can I ask one more bonus question? Is there a way to get a list of ip addresses with the last time users have logged in from these ip addresses?

Comment: take a look at my edit

Answer (score 4):

`who` is good, but simply `w` is better.

Comment: It would be nice if you explained the difference :-)

Comment: It's a personal taste thing. But if I had to convince someone I would say that `w` is shorter than `who` but prints out more. So we get more for less. :) Or I would just quote from the manpages: **who - show who is logged on** but **w - Show who is logged on and what they are doing.** And it is obvious that we want to see what others are doing :D

Comment: Please edit your answer accordingly - I myself know what I am using :-))

Comment: Why? For me the answer is good. Simple question simple answer.

Comment: Only answers are kept here - comments will vanish some time - so what you say in a comment will get lost eventually.

Answer (score 1):

and in realtime:

```
$ watch -n 1 w
```